# Focus back textbox on focus out if does not have required value

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I am focusing back textbox if it does not have required values. Textbox is not focusing back after execution of this function. However it is alerting (`alert("Must be 1");`) correctly.

```
$("#textbox").blur(function(event){
       if ($(this).text != "1"){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert("Must be 1");
          $(this).focus(); 
        }
});
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$("#textbox").blur(function(event){
       var tb = this;
       if ($(this).val() != "1"){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert("Must be 1");
          setTimeout( function() { $(tb).focus(); }, 1);
        }
});
```

By putting the ".focus()" call in a timeout, you make the switch happen in a separate event loop. Note also that you were trying to get the value incorrectly (".text"), and also that I have to preserve the reference to the element in "tb".

I suspect that this might not work in Safari. Safari is *really* reluctant to obey ".focus()" calls, and it gets confused by "alert()".  Of course, if you deliver the message to the user by some other means (and please do so :-), then it might work.